# Edit value in pandas dataframe based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas

Here an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'file':['filename1','filename2','filename3','filename4','filename5'],
'prop1':['True','False','False','True','False'],
'prop2':['False','True','False','False','True'],
'prop3':['False','False','True','False','False']
})
        file  prop1  prop2    prop3
0  filename1   True  False    False
1  filename2  False   True    False
2  filename3  False  False     True
3  filename4   True  False    False
4  filename5  False   True    False
```

I need to edit "file" based on prop1, prop2, prop3 value like this:

```
           file
filename1:prop1
filename2:prop2
filename3:prop3
filename4:prop1
filename5:prop2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if the values ​​are str type you should use better `bool` type since you are using more memory unnecessarily**

you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to convert to bool and a for loop + [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to check:

```
for key in df.columns[1:]: 
    df[key]=df[key].apply(lambda x:eval(x))
    df['file'].mask(df[key],df['file']+':'+ key,inplace=True)
print(df)

              file  prop1  prop2  prop3
0  filename1:prop1   True  False  False
1  filename2:prop2  False   True  False
2  filename3:prop3  False  False   True
3  filename4:prop1   True  False  False
4  filename5:prop2  False   True  False
```

---

```
print(df['prop1'])

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: prop1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) through `axis=1`

```
df['file'] = df.file + ':' + df.filter(like='prop').idxmax(1)
```

---

```
             file
0  filename1:prop1
1  filename2:prop2
2  filename3:prop3
3  filename4:prop1
4  filename5:prop2
```